# Feeling bad about an overuse of get_option

Tags: wordpress

I've been working with the settings API getting my head wrapped around it.  Now that I feel I have a decent understanding of how to use it, I want to optimize how I'm doing it a bit.

My main concern is the use of `get_option` on every callback to create each of the settings inputs.  I was planning on caching them so I didn't need to call `get_option` 10+ times.

My question is, before I do my caching, does wordpress have its own per-page load cache for get_option?

Thanks,
Max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>No, WordPress doesn't have that kind of cache. It even calls get_option() too often.</strike>

EDIT #1: `wp_load_alloption()` will load every single options from database to cache, so `get_option()` will only load from database if none found on it's cache.

See below (the original answer) To reduce the use of get_option():

I prever to wrap them all to an object to reduce the usage of get_option. I've always do these first thing on my themes:

```
global $mytheme;

$mytheme = new stdClass;
$mytheme->something = get_option( 'something' );
```

I do for each setting that repeatedly used on my theme so get_option will only be loaded once.

Next I want the option to be call, I just use:

```
function something() {
    global $mytheme;

    $something = $mytheme->something; 

    return $something;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the info; I might just implement it myself, can't believe Wordpress wouldn't save something so easy to save perpage load.  I'm requesting the same object (in the same class) 10+ times.  This'll definitely help on the queries!

Comment: Wordpress actually loads most options on each page with autoload: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/27717/are-all-options-loaded-to-memory-on-each-request

Comment: Yes actually, after examining get_option() function, I found out that since 2.8, WP has already cache the get_option results. So on second call it will load from cache.

Answer (score 0):

you can store multiple values in 1 option. Just feed `update_option` or `add_option` an array.

On the caching note take a look at these links:
http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/wordpress-transients-api-practical-examples
http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API

Comment: I didn't mention it, but I have been doing that (storing every option in one array).  The issue is that I need that array in many places throughout my plugin.  I plan on saving to a variable each page load (instead of calling get_option), but I don't want to do that (and waste memory) if Wordpress already does.

Comment: @mazzzzz also take a look at the autoload: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/27717/are-all-options-loaded-to-memory-on-each-request